# issue with UITapGestureRecognizer for a button

Tags: iphone, uibutton, uitapgesturerecognizer

I've done the following thing:

```
 buttonPlaylistView = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width *(urlList.count+1), 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
            buttonPlaylistView.tag = 0;

 UITapGestureRecognizer *doubleTap3 = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleDoubleTap:)];
            [doubleTap3 setNumberOfTapsRequired:2];
            [buttonPlaylistView addGestureRecognizer:doubleTap3];
            [doubleTap3 release];

-(void) handleDoubleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender{
    if(sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)

    int x = [sender tag];
    return;
}
```

But I get `SIGAGRT` at this line: `int x = [sender tag];` saying:

```
[UITapGestureRecognizer tag]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x61280b0
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITapGestureRecognizer tag]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x61280b0'
```

NOW:What's the problem and what's the solution for this?Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
-(void) handleDoubleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
    if(sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
    {
      int x = [sender.view tag];
    }
}
```

Will fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

An **UITapGestureRecognizer** does not have a property named tag - as you see, the sender you get is **NOT** the button. You have to access the **buttonPlayListView** directly, like

`int x = [buttonPlayListView tag];`

or otherwise remember which button you want to access.

Comment: and how could I remember if I create let say 100 buttons.I remember by using TAG.That's why I use tag...to remember the button:)

Comment: You could subclass the UIGestureRecognizer, adding  property myButton to it and set it when assigning the gesture recognizer to a button. Then you can cast the UIGestureRecognizer you get as sender to MyGestureRecognizer and get the myButton property. Or you make a NSMutableDictionary class variable and set the button as value for the gesture recognizers as key, e.g. [allMyGestureRecognizerButtons setObject:buttonPlaylistView forKey:doubleTap3] - then you get the button by using the sender as key into the dictionary.

Comment: You might also still get a single tap on your button (not sure, but you can check) and remember which button was single-tapped last ...

Comment: Actually, the UIGestureRecognizer knows which view it is attached to (see its view property).

Comment: @till Indeed, that's a nice solution :-). I looked for that in the docs too, but I always forget to check the parent classes ... I wish Apple would include superclass properties and functions in the documentation for the child class, too ...

Comment: @TheEye right, happens to me as well - especially when it comes to the "well-known" classes and their superclasses; e.g. never underestimate the power of UIView or UIControl :D.

Answer (score 1):

Even though I'm quite sure that you're going about this the wrong way, adding a double tap gesture recognizer to a UIButton, there is a way you can still perform the task you require that shouldn't be too much work for you.
You've made the comment

> and how could I remember if I create let say 100 buttons

to one of the answers, the one which highlights what the issue is that's causing your SIGBART. UIGestureRecognizer does not have a tag property.

Here's what you could do, is to iterate through all the subviews of your [self view] and find the one that has the same UIGestureRecognizer, it's not the prettiest solution, and the more subview's you have the longer the loop will take.  But it'll do what you seem to be  looking for, so if you're adding .

In your handleDoubleTap function you could do the following

```
-(void) handleDoubleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
    if(sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
    {
        int iButtonTag = -1 //This is important later to escape the below for loop as we don't need to needlessly go around in circles
        for(UIView* psubView in [[self view] subviews])
        {
            if( [psubView isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]] )
            {
                UIButton* pButton = (UIButton*)psubView;
                for(UIGestureRecognizer* pGesture in [pButton gestureRecognizers] )
                {
                     if( pGesture == sender )//this is the button we're after
                     {
                         iButtonTag = [pButton tag];
                         break;
                     }
                }
                if( iButton != -1 )//found what we came for
                {
                    break;
                }
             }
        }
        //do what ever it was you needed to do now that you have the views tag, or you could have kept a reference to the button etc.
    }
 }
```

That should solve your problem. Alternatively if you're going to be adding buttons to subviews of subviews it would be better to keep track of your UIButtons in an NSMutableArray , you would do this by creating a class property (or member variable) and adding the buttons to this using the 'addObject:' function of NSMutableArray. Then instead of the line

```
for(UIView* psubView in [[self view] subviews])
```

above you could exchange that for

```
for( UIButton* pButton in m_pMutableButtonArray )
```

where "m_pMutableButtonArray" is the variable name you gave to your NSMutableArray you were storing the UIButtons in.  This also means you would do away with the following if isKindOfClass test on the following line.

That should fix your problem.

Comment: UIGestureRecognizer does not have a tag property.Right, but UIGestureRecognizer.view has tag property;).The issue was solved in @Till way.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why are you putting a UITapGestureRecognizer in a button? The button already handles that for you and will send you a callback, you can add a target to a button using this UIControl method

```
- (void)addTarget:(id)target action:(SEL)action forControlEvents:(UIControlEvents)controlEvents
```

Comment: because when I double cilck I want to do something.Understand?The button handles simple click

Comment: In that case you shouldn't have a button at all, just a view with 2 gesture recognizers one for single tap, one for double tap. Understand.

Comment: Then require the double tap to fail for the single tap, the button wont do that.